# How to make an existing caching Nginx proxy use another proxy to bypass a firewall?

Tags: nginx, firewall, proxy, cache

My question is about using Nginx as a proxy behind another proxy. (Somewhat confusing.)

I want to set up Nginx so it acts as a caching proxy server to an npm mirror. Here is the link:
http://eng.yammer.com/a-private-npm-cache/

On my local machine, which is not restricted by a firewall, the following configuration works fine:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/npm/data levels=1:2 keys_zone=npm:20m max_size=1000m
inactive=365d;
proxy_temp_path /var/cache/npm/tmp;

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name classen.abc.lan;
   location / {
      proxy_pass http://registry.npmjs.org/;
      proxy_cache npm;
      proxy_cache_valid 200 302 365d;
      proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
      sub_filter 'registry.npmjs.org' 'classen.abc.lan';
      sub_filter_once off;
      sub_filter_types application/json;
   }
}
```

Now I want to apply it to a server that is behind an additional firewall. In the logs, I can confirm that it accesses the correct upstream IP, but the request fails because of the internal firewall.

We have one internal proxy, which I can use to bypass the firewall, for example:

```
$ curl http://registry.npmjs.org
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
$ http_proxy=http://proxy.abc.lan:1234/ curl http://registry.npmjs.org
... succeeds ...
```

This trick does not work with Nginx, as it ignores the `http_proxy` environment variable. After reading the documentation, I still could not figure out how to modify the configuration, so that it can use the proxy internally.

**Is it possible to combine both solutions?** It is important that the caching still works, otherwise, you can just use the external mirror registry.npmjs.org directly.

Maybe, Nginx should use the internal proxy (proxy.abc.lan) as `proxy_pass`, but then how does the internal proxy know that the request should be sent to the external npm mirror (http://registry.npmjs.org)?

**Update to Lukas answer**

I tried Lukas solution:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ "http://registry.npmjs.org$1" break;
proxy_pass http://proxy.abc.lan:1234;
```

The logs show that the URL is rewritten but it results in a redirect (triggered by `curl classen.abc.lan/test-url`):

```
2014/03/24 11:31:16 [notice] 13827#0: *2 rewritten redirect: "http://registry.npmjs.org/test-url", client: 172.18.40.33, server: classen.abc.lan, request: "GET /test-url HTTP/1.1", host: "classen.abc.lan"
```

The result of the curl call is not the expected JSON string from http://registry.npmjs.org but a html page generated by Nginx:

```
$ curl classen.abc.lan/test-url
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.7</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue with Lukas's solution is [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) , which automatically turns everything with http(s) at the front into a 302.

If you instead do the rewrite in two stages - the second one 'break' - it should work. e.g.

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ "://registry.npmjs.org$1";
rewrite ^(.*)$ "http$1" break;
proxy_pass http://proxy.abc.lan:1234;
```

I suspect there's a nicer way to do this, but it appears to work.

Comment: This really worked!!!
I am using nginx as forward proxy behind a corporate proxy. My config:
    `rewrite ^(.*)$ "://$http_host$uri$is_args$args" break;`
    `rewrite ^(.*)$ "http$uri$is_args$args" break;`
    `proxy_pass http://proxy.abc.lan:3128;`

Comment: Should the first rewrite not "break"? Also, I think people would appreciate it if you can mention https proxy is not supported by Nginx.

Comment: @blurrcat you are right. In addition, it does not support reverse proxy to https website.

Answer (score 3):

[RFC 2616, Section 5.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2) states

> The absoluteURI form is REQUIRED when the request is being made to a proxy.
> *[...]*
> An example Request-Line would be:
>
> ```
>   GET http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
> ```

So what you are supposed to do is pass the request to the proxy with those modified directives:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ "http://registry.npmjs.org$1" break;
proxy_pass http://proxy.abc.lan:1234;
```

According to [the nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass), using `rewrite ... break;` will force nginx to use the *rewritten URI* (now an absolute URI as the protocol requires) instead of trying to build it from the `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I could not get it to work. Maybe I am missing something. I edited my answer to show what I have tried.

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be simpler than either of the examples above.  They are using rewrite to rewrite the url, I think you can use proxy_pass but pass the url to the proxy setting the host header param to the location you want to go to.  e.g.

```
http {

  upstream corporate_proxy  {
      server web-proxy.mycorp.com:8080;
  }

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name classen.abc.lan;
   location / {
      proxy_pass_header on;
      proxy_set_header Host "registry.npmjs.org";
      proxy_pass http://corporate_proxy;
      proxy_cache npm;
      proxy_cache_valid 200 302 365d;
      proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
      sub_filter 'registry.npmjs.org' 'classen.abc.lan';
      sub_filter_once off;
      sub_filter_types application/json;
   }
}
```

Comment: I also needed `proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";` for the sub_filter to work. As seen in https://serverfault.com/questions/547060/why-does-sub-filter-seem-to-not-work-when-used-in-conjunction-with-proxy-pass#comment763096_548946